# How to add options dynamically in a combobox with htmlservice and javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I really need you help in this, any help provided would be very well received.

I have 2 comboboxes

```
<select name="combo1" id="combo1">
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<select name="combo2" id="combo2">

</select>
```

And when I select an option in the first combobox, options in the second combobox should change according the selection.

For example: 
if in the combo1 is selected `"April"`, I want to show the options:`"Texas","NY"`.
but if `"November"` is selected I want to change the states that I want to show.

I would really appreciate your help in this!

Comment: Please provide more logic for the `JavaScript` part.  Have you already tried writing any code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should set onchange of combo1 and then check the value of it, i wrote it for you with javascript:

```
var combo1 = document.getElementById("combo1");
var combo2 = document.getElementById("combo2");

combo1.onchnage = function(){
    switch(this.value){
        case "April":
             combo2.innerHTML = "<option value='Texas'>Texas</option><option value='NY'>NY</option>";
             break;
        case "November":
             combo2.innerHTML = "<option value='foo'>foo</option><option value='bar'>bar</option>";
             break;
    }

}
```